# Class member function in variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to write a variadic function to generate a gmock matcher that checks for zero-ness of multiple properties at once.

```
// Class with three properties.
class Vec3 {
 public:
  double x() const;
  double y() const;
  double z() const;
};

using ::testing::AllOf;
using ::testing::Property;

Vec3 vec3;
// I could do this...
EXPECT_THAT(vec3, AllOf(Property(&Vec3::x, Eq(0.0)),
    Property(&Vec3::y, Eq(0.0)), Property(&Vec3::z, Eq(0.0)));

// But I'd want to do something like this...
EXPECT_THAT(vec3, PropertiesAreZero(&Vec3::x, &Vec3::y, &Vec3::z));
```

I seem to be unable to make progress on writing a variardic function that generates the equivalent matcher. Here's what I've been trying:

```
template <typename T, typename M, typename P>
Matcher<T> PropertiesAre(M matcher, P(T::*... args)()) {
    return AllOf(Property(args, matcher)...);
};

template <typename T, typename... Others>
Matcher<T> PropertiesAreZero(Others... others) {
    return PropertiesAre(Eq(0.0), others...);
}

Vec3 vec3;
EXPECT_THAT(vec3, PropertiesAreZero(&Vec3::x, &Vec3::y, &Vec3::z));
```

I'm getting the following compilation error:

```
error: type 'P (T::*)()' of function parameter pack does not contain any unexpanded parameter packs
Matcher<T> PropertiesAre(M matcher, P(T::*... args)()) {
                                    ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
error: pack expansion does not contain any unexpanded parameter packs
  return AllOf(Property(args, matcher)...);
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
error: no matching function for call to 'PropertiesAre'
          PropertiesAre(Ne(0.0),
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
gmock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:5240:60: note: expanded from macro 'EXPECT_THAT'
    ::testing::internal::MakePredicateFormatterFromMatcher(matcher), value)
                                                           ^~~~~~~
gtest/include/gtest/gtest_pred_impl.h:117:23: note: expanded from macro 'EXPECT_PRED_FORMAT1'
  GTEST_PRED_FORMAT1_(pred_format, v1, GTEST_NONFATAL_FAILURE_)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
gtest/include/gtest/gtest_pred_impl.h:104:17: note: expanded from macro 'GTEST_PRED_FORMAT1_'
  GTEST_ASSERT_(pred_format(#v1, v1), \
                ^~~~~~~~~~~
gtest/include/gtest/gtest_pred_impl.h:80:52: note: expanded from macro 'GTEST_ASSERT_'
  if (const ::testing::AssertionResult gtest_ar = (expression)) \
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 4 were provided
Matcher<T> PropertiesAre(M matcher, P(T::*... args)()) {
           ^
error: no matching function for call to 'PropertiesAreZero'
          PropertiesAreZero(
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gmock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:5240:60: note: expanded from macro 'EXPECT_THAT'
    ::testing::internal::MakePredicateFormatterFromMatcher(matcher), value)
                                                           ^~~~~~~
gtest/include/gtest/gtest_pred_impl.h:117:23: note: expanded from macro 'EXPECT_PRED_FORMAT1'
  GTEST_PRED_FORMAT1_(pred_format, v1, GTEST_NONFATAL_FAILURE_)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
gtest/include/gtest/gtest_pred_impl.h:104:17: note: expanded from macro 'GTEST_PRED_FORMAT1_'
  GTEST_ASSERT_(pred_format(#v1, v1), \
                ^~~~~~~~~~~
gtest/include/gtest/gtest_pred_impl.h:80:52: note: expanded from macro 'GTEST_ASSERT_'
  if (const ::testing::AssertionResult gtest_ar = (expression)) \
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
Matcher<T> PropertiesAreZero(Others... others) {
           ^
error: no matching function for call to 'PropertiesAreZero'
              PropertiesAreZero(
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'd really appreciate any help I can get with this. I've been up against this for a whole day now.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can debug it instead of just looking at your code.

Comment: Your `PropertiesAre` isn’t even variadic, since it has no template parameter packs.

Answer (score 1):

Without having the definitions of things like `AllOf` to hand, it's a little tricky to get this exactly right, but here's my stab at what you're going for, and then I'll try to explain what you're getting wrong.

```
template<typename R, typename T>
using const_member_ptr = R(T::*)() const;

template<typename T, typename M, typename... R>
Matcher<T> PropertiesAre(M matcher, const_member_ptr<R,T> ...args)
{
    return AllOf<T>(Property(args, matcher)...);
}

template <typename T, typename... R>
Matcher<T> PropertiesAreZero(const_member_ptr<R,T>... others)
{
    return PropertiesAre<T>(Eq(0.0), others...);
}
```

The first issue is that in your version of `PropertiesAreZero`, the compiler can't infer what `T` is. The compiler has to be able to infer from the parameters of the function, so you have to give it something to pattern-match against. In the case here, I've assumed that you're calling const member functions, and when the compiler pattern-matches against that, it can infer `T`.

Since we then have `T`, I explicitly provide it to `PropertiesAre` even though we could again infer it. A problem with your `PropertiesAre` is that you have the ellipsis to expand a parameter pack, but it's not actually a variadic template. I've fixed that by making the R template parameter variadic.

For reference, these are the definitions I guessed:

```
template<typename T>
class Matcher{};

struct Eq
{ Eq(double){} };

template<typename T, typename... X>
Matcher<T> AllOf(X ...x) {}

template<typename P, typename M>
int Property(P p, M m) {}
```

And this compiling on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/Gyeq1E).